# Handling Unicode Escape Sequences For a Hawaiian Keyboard In Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, keyboard

Aloha, I am trying to modify a Chrome OS keyboard layout I found on GitHub to work for Hawaiian language. I've not coded Javascript in years and even at that my skill were fairly rudimentary.

The problem I have is that the keyboard this is derived from only used single characters on the keyboard, and for our Hawaiian vowel-macron characters I need to use Unicode escape sequences, and this crashes the keyboard. I assume I need to handle the Unicode in some manner before it is invoked on the keyboard and I'm simply not sure where or how to do that. You will see the escape sequences in the lut variable. Thanks in advance.

```
    /*
Copyright 2014 Google Inc. All rights reserved.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
*/
var AltGr = { PLAIN: "plain", ALTERNATE: "alternate" };
var Shift = { PLAIN: "plain", SHIFTED: "shifted" };

var contextID = -1;
var altGrState = AltGr.PLAIN;
var shiftState = Shift.PLAIN;
var lastRemappedKeyEvent = undefined;

var lut = {
"KeyA": { "plain": {"plain": "a", "shifted": "A"}, "alternate": {"plain": "\0101", "shifted":"\0100"}, "code": "KeyA"},
"Quote": { "plain": {"plain": "ə", "shifted": "Ə"}, "alternate": {"plain": "‘", "shifted":""}, "code": "Quote"},
 };
    

chrome.input.ime.onFocus.addListener(function(context) {
  contextID = context.contextID;
});

function updateAltGrState(keyData) {
  altGrState = (keyData.code == "AltRight") ? ((keyData.type == "keydown") ? AltGr.ALTERNATE : AltGr.PLAIN)
                                              : altGrState;
}

function updateShiftState(keyData) {
  shiftState = ((keyData.shiftKey && !(keyData.capsLock)) || (!(keyData.shiftKey) && keyData.capsLock)) ? 
                 Shift.SHIFTED : Shift.PLAIN;
}

function isPureModifier(keyData) {
  return (keyData.key == "Shift") || (keyData.key == "Ctrl") || (keyData.key == "Alt");
}

function isRemappedEvent(keyData) {
  // hack, should check for a sender ID (to be added to KeyData)
  return lastRemappedKeyEvent != undefined &&
         (lastRemappedKeyEvent.key == keyData.key &&
          lastRemappedKeyEvent.code == keyData.code &&
          lastRemappedKeyEvent.type == keyData.type
         ); // requestID would be different so we are not checking for it  
}


chrome.input.ime.onKeyEvent.addListener(
    function(engineID, keyData) {
      var handled = false;
      
      if (isRemappedEvent(keyData)) {
        lastRemappedKeyEvent = undefined;
        return handled;
      }

      updateAltGrState(keyData);
      updateShiftState(keyData);
                
      if (lut[keyData.code]) {
          var remappedKeyData = keyData;
          remappedKeyData.key = lut[keyData.code][altGrState][shiftState];
          remappedKeyData.code = lut[keyData.code].code;
        
        if (chrome.input.ime.sendKeyEvents != undefined) {
          chrome.input.ime.sendKeyEvents({"contextID": contextID, "keyData": [remappedKeyData]});
          handled = true;
          lastRemappedKeyEvent = remappedKeyData;
        } else if (keyData.type == "keydown" && !isPureModifier(keyData)) {
          chrome.input.ime.commitText({"contextID": contextID, "text": remappedKeyData.key});
          handled = true;
        }
      }
      
      return handled;
});
```